# Create constant for the maximum value the random number can be?

Tags: java

I want to create a simple Math game that uses two random numbers and then 
allows the user to input the answer for each of the following operations: (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and power). I don't know how to set the constant for a maximum a random number can be as a constant.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Random generator = new Random();

         // create a variable that will hold the first random number
         int random1 = generator.nextInt();

         // create a variable that will hold the second random number
         int random2 = generator.nextInt();

         // create a constant for the maximum the random number can be
```

Comment: Do you know about javadoc?

Comment: Are you looking for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the random class documentation at [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

`int upperLimit = 100;`

`int random1 = generator.nextInt(uperLimit);`

`int random2 = generator.nextInt(uperLimit);`

Will give you number less than 100

Comment: so this needs to be changed,  int random1 = generator.nextInt(UpperLimit); and I need to add int UpperLimit=100;. Its telling me that UpperLimit cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: I have edited my code. This will now give 2 random numbers random1 and random2  both with upper limit 100. and if this works dont forget to accept the answer

Comment: variable names in java are case sensitive. Are you sure you are using the right variable names in your code its upperLimit not UpperLimit.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Random.nextInt(), the maximum the number can be is (2^31)-1 (2147483647).

If you were to pass a value into Random.nextInt(), such as 5, the range of possible outcomes is 0-5.

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

Comment: The max is actually 2^31 - 1.

Comment: It's actually 2^31 - 1. I made a mistake in my original comment.